# Meteor helper methods

Tags: meteor

I want to write some helper functions that I can use in my other JavaScript files.

It [says here](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp):

> Some JavaScript libraries only work when placed in the client/compatibility subdirectory. Files in this directory are executed without being **wrapped in a new variable scope**.

It seems a bit bizarre to me that I should have to throw all my libraries in a folder called `compatibility`. Generally "compatible" stuff is for legacy code that hasn't been upgraded to the new style. Is there no way to export modules so that I can access them in my other files?

---

Using this pattern now:

```
Util = (function(exports) {
    exports.getFileExtension = function(filename) {
        var i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
        return (i < 0) ? '' : filename.substr(i);
    };

   // more functions

    return exports;
})(typeof Util !== 'undefined' ? Util : {});
```

Not sure if that's the best or not...but it appears to work.

Comment: Please read "Namespacing and Modules" at http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/08/14/meteor-065-namespacing-modularity-new-build-system-source-maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be bizarre, you are right.  Write your own code, just put it somewhere and it works.  This refers to complicated frameworks that make a lot of functions all over the place, where no one has 'tamed' them to only expose a root object that all its powers spring from.

Please read "Namespacing and Modules" at
http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/08/14/meteor-065-namespacing-modularity-new-build-system-source-maps

It's helping you with built in maintainability for avoiding collisions with other things you write, which is largely what namespaces is for.

A good practice is to have your own helper object, named helper or util, where you put grouped things:

```
utils = {
  distance_between: function(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2) {
      var radiusEarth = 3963.1676; // miles radius earth
      var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
...
  displayHumanReadableTime: function(timestamp){
    var a = new Date(timestamp);
```

Comment: "just put it somewhere and it works" -- except that it doesn't. Are you suggesting I leave off the `var` to force it to be global?

Comment: "Are you suggesting I leave off the var to force it to be global?" => Yes, cause if you don't, your helper will be LOCAL to the source file where it is defined thus unreachable to other scripts. If you want to define a Handlebars helper, remember to use Handlebars.registerHelper("myHelper",function(arguments){...});

Comment: Meteor.something works.  var something works.  Export works. Just try to add one thing at this level, rather than many.  This prevents things bleeding.

Comment: @JimMack `exports` doesn't look like it works. Maybe in package, but not in a regular file. Shouldn't `Meteor.*` be reserved for meteor-related stuff? That leaves us with just globals. Which is fine; I just want to know the recommended way of doing things.

Comment: @Mark, Sorry I was thinking about export from packages. According to https://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages and  https://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing, export is necessary from packages. 

I think Meteor.helpers or Meteor.utils is a valid interpretation of meteor-related stuff.  Some day your library may be part of meteor core! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to write Utility method then it can be written using the ECMA6 Script standard.

Write your method by exporting once in method.js and use it by importing in the desired file(s)

Ex: 
export const MyUtilityMethod = function (){...} in /method.js

import {MyUtilityMethod} from './method.js'

Hope this helps.